# Stacked plot of multirow data

Tags: python, pandas, stacked-chart

I am fairly new to pandas and matplotlib, and I am not sure what the propper way is to achieve the following:

---

I have below (example) data `so_df`:

IN:

```
    import pandas as pd

    so_df = pd.DataFrame({
        "CATEGORY" : ["A", "B", "A", "B"],
        "CONTEXT"  : [ 1 ,  1 ,  0 ,  0],
        "COUNT"    : [100, 111, 50 , 55]
    })
    so_df
```

OUT:

```
      CATEGORY  CONTEXT  COUNT
    0        A        1    100
    1        B        1    111
    2        A        0     50
    3        B        0     55
```

---

Now I want to create a [stacked bar-plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYrok.png) with `y="COUNT"` by `CATEGORY` and `X="CONTEXT"`.
The only way I know how to achieve this is by slicing and merging like so:

IN:

```
    cat_a_df = so_df[so_df["CATEGORY"] == "A"] \
        .rename(columns={"COUNT" : "COUNT A"}) \
        .loc[:,["CONTEXT", "COUNT A"]]

    cat_b_df = so_df[so_df["CATEGORY"] == "B"] \
        .rename(columns={"COUNT" : "COUNT B"}) \
        .loc[:,["CONTEXT", "COUNT B"]]

    stacked_df = cat_a_df.merge(cat_b_df, on="CONTEXT")
    stacked_df
```

OUT:

```
       CONTEXT  COUNT A  COUNT B
    0        1      100      111
    1        0       50       55
```

And then plot the new dataframe as usual:

```
    stacked_df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, x="CONTEXT")
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYrok.png)

---

But this seems way to complicated for what seems like a rather simple task.
Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it all in one line:

```
so_df.groupby(['CONTEXT', 'CATEGORY']).sum()['COUNT'].unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

We group by `'CONTEXT'` and `'CATEGORY`', then apply `.sum()` to get from a `groupby` object to a dataframe - in your case, the sum won't do anything. Finally we `unstack` to get one column for `A` and one column for `B`. Plotting this gives:

[image]